# Looping through a nested list within a dictionary in python

Tags: python

In my loop_genre function i'm trying to loop through a nested list inside a dictionary. When i try to i'm unsuccessful. What i tried to do was words_list = dict['movies']['title']['genre'][1]['title']['genre'][2]['title']['genre'] which would allow me to iterate through the list without a loop but it defeats the purpose of the assignment which is to loop through nested values. The output should be a line containing commas after each word. Can anyone help me solve this? Thank you

Cheers

Liam

def main():

```
  def name_id():
        print("Hi Joe, my name is " + dict['name'] + ' ' 'and my student ID is ' + dict['student_id'] + '.')
  def loop_pizzatoppings():
        new_tuple = ('Tomatoes', 'Onions', 'Napalm')
        for t in new_tuple:
              dict['pizza_toppings'].append(t)
        words_list = dict['pizza_toppings']
        words_list.sort()
        word = ''
        for w in words_list:
              word += w + "," " "
        print("My ideal pizza has " + word)
  def loop_genre():
        word2 = ''
        for w in dict['movies']['title']['genre']:
              word2 += w + ', '




        print("I like to watch " + word2)
  def movie_loop():
        word3 = ''
        for w in dict['movies']:
              word3 += w['title'] + ', '
        print('Some of my favorites are ' + word3)


  dict = {
        'name': 'Liam',
        'student_id': '10261507',
        'pizza_toppings': [
              'Pepperoni',
              'Mushrooms',
              'Peppers',

        ],

        'movies': [
              {'title': 'Star Wars',
              'genre': [
              'Sci-Fi',
              'Action',
              'Space opera',
              'Adventure',
              'Fantasy',
              ]
              },
              {'title': 'Deadpool',
              'genre': [
              'Comedy',
              'Romance',
              'Superhero',


               ]
              }
        ]
  }
  extra_movie={'title': 'The Dark Knight Rises', 'genre': ['Drama', 'Thriller', 'Crime fiction']}
  dict['movies'].append(extra_movie)




  name_id()
  loop_pizzatoppings()
  loop_genre()
  movie_loop()
```

main()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:
Here are all the genres on one line (along with replacing the last comma with a period. As mentioned in the comments, this is not very pythonic. Hopefully someone else can give a better answer.

```
def loop_genre():
    word2 = 'I like to watch '
    for i in range(len(dict['movies'])):
        for x in range(len(dict['movies'][i]['genre'])):
            word2 += dict['movies'][i]['genre'][x] + ', '
    print(word2[:-2] + '.')
```

Not sure if the output you are looking for is one genre per line, but here is a way to iterate through all of the genres. Basically it is just a nested for loop using index numbers instead of dict keys.

```
    def loop_genre():
    word2 = 'I like to watch '
    for i in range(len(dict['movies'])):
        for x in range(len(dict['movies'][i]['genre'])):
            word2 = 'I like to watch ' + dict['movies'][i]['genre'][x]
            print(word2)
```

Comment: This is not very pythonic code: we usually avoid indices when they're not strictly needed. Instead of `for i in range(len(some_dict)):`, we prefer to do `for key in some_dict:` or `for key, value in some_dict.items():`. It's easier to read, and more efficient to boot.

Comment: The first answer gives me the output i want just not in a single line. If the answer can be changed so that it outputs the genres in a single line where each word is separated by a comma, that's all i will need to complete the assignment.